# Platforming Game on Windows Console Application and Improving Input

Tags: c, input, console

I am currently making a platform game using the Windows Console. However, I have been running into an issue when I issue multiple commands.

For example, when I have my character running in one direction and then press jump, the fact that the run key being held is forgotten and must be pressed again.

Is there an input method that can check which keys are being held or pressed? Or rather, a way of checking for duplicate inputs?

For reference, here is my current code:
http://pastebin.com/2y6Rf6rb

Input method I am currently using is this:

```
/*** Keyboard Input ***/
/* Number of Events */
DWORD numEvents = 0;

/* Events from Console Read */
DWORD numEventsRead = 0;

/* Find Number of Console Events */
GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents(rHnd, &numEvents);

/*If there is an Event */
if(numEvents != 0)
{
    /* Create Buffer to Store Events */
    INPUT_RECORD *eventBuffer = new INPUT_RECORD[numEvents];

    /* Read Console Events to that Buffer and Save that many Events */
    ReadConsoleInput(rHnd, eventBuffer, numEvents, &numEventsRead);

    /* Cycle through Events that have Happened */
    for(DWORD i = 0; i < numEventsRead; i++)
    {
        /* If Event was a Key Press */
        if(eventBuffer[i].EventType == KEY_EVENT && eventBuffer[i].Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown == TRUE)
        {
            /* Right ('d' Key) 0x44*/
            if(eventBuffer[i].Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode == 0x44)
            {
                key = 'd';

                for(y = 0; y < 3; y ++)
                {
                    if(gdisplay[PY - y][PX + 4] == square1[0] && gdisplay[PY - y][PX + 4 + 1] == square1[1])
                    {
                        movecheck = 0;
                    }
                }

                if(momentum < 0)
                {
                    momentum++;
                }

                else if(movecheck == 1)
                {
                    PX+=2;
                    momentum++;

                    if(panime == 1)
                    {
                        panime = 2;
                    }

                    else if(panime == 2)
                    {
                        panime = 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            /* Left ('a' Key) 0x41*/
            else if(eventBuffer[i].Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode == 0x41)
            {
                key = 'a';
                if((PX - 2) >= 2)
                {
                    for(y = 0; y < 3; y ++)
                    {
                        if(gdisplay[PY - y][PX - 4] == square1[0] && gdisplay[PY - y][PX - 4 + 1] == square1[1])
                        {
                            movecheck = 0;
                        }
                    }

                    if(momentum > 0)
                    {
                        momentum--;
                    }

                    else if(movecheck == 1)
                    {
                        PX-=2;
                        momentum--;

                        if(panime == 1)
                        {
                            panime = 2;
                        }

                        else if(panime == 2)
                        {
                            panime = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            /* Jump (Spacebar) VK_SPACE*/
            else if(eventBuffer[i].Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode == VK_SPACE)
            {
                if(jump == 0)
                {
                    jump++;
                    PY-=2;
                }
            }
        }
        /* Max Momentum */
        if(momentum > 4)
        {
            momentum = 4;
        }

        if(momentum < -4)
        {
            momentum = -4;
        }
        rewind(stdin);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could try is when the `keyDown` is issued you could set some flag to true, like `rightKeyPressed = true` and then you could also check for a `keyUp` in which case you would do `rightKeyPressed = false` and do this for each of the running keys. I believe the problem that you're running into is that when you press a key other than the one you are holding, you no longer receive keyDown events for that key. So, you need some way to save that a particular key is being pressed until it is actually released. That way, when you interrupt with a jump command, the `rightKeyPressed` (or whichever direction) will still be true even though the system isn't receiving `keyDown` events for that key.

This will require some significant refactoring since you are currently only keeping track of the `key` variable. As an example, here is some fake code that should demonstrate the point:

```
public void keyPressed(Key key){
    if(key==RIGHT)
      runningRight = true;
      runningLeft = false;
    else if(key==LEFT)
      runningLeft = true;
      runningRight = false;
    else if(e.getKeyCode()==CTRL)
      jump = true;
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
    if(key==RIGHT)
      runningRight = false;
    else if(key==LEFT)
      runningLeft = false;
}
```

Good luck

Comment: @Aethersong did that end up being helpful? If I wasn't clear, let me know. If it was helpful though, you should accept the answer.